# Mysqli driver on codeigniter 3 not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

In CodeIgniter version 3.0, DB Driver "mysql" is deprecated, and the new recommended driver for MySql is "mysqli".

But my queries don't work when I use mysqli, and when I switch back to "mysql" driver an error is displayed:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
Line Number: 136

...
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging **why** your queries don't work under MySQLi?

Comment: Even if the SQL command is the same for mysql and mysqli drivers?

Comment: SQL for mysqli driver
`SELECT `id`
FROM `users`
WHERE `username` = 'ronaldob'
AND `password` = '123' `

SQL for mysql driver
`SELECT `id`
FROM `users`
WHERE `username` = 'ronaldob'
AND `password` = '123' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch back to mysqli and use this SQL

```
SELECT
users.`id`
FROM `users`
WHERE
users.`name` = "ronaldob" AND
users.`password` = "123"
```

I usually use `` quotes  and that helps alot avoiding SQL keywords , see a complete MySQL keyword list here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Perfectly, thanks Nassim.